# Nightmare-iframe dynamic iframe name

Tags: javascript, nightmare

how can I access iframe with random generated name using nightmare-iframe plugin?

I have tried

```
var name = yield nightmare
  .goto(defaultUrl)
  .click('.btn-login')
  .wait('iframe')
  .evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
  });

yield nightmare.use(iframe.withFrameName(name, function(IFnightmare) {
  IFnightmare
    .type('input[name=username]', 'username')
    .type('input[name=password]', 'password')
    .click('button[type=submit]')
}))
```

but this code ends with - TypeError: Cannot read property 'switchToFrame' of undefined

Comment: What version of nightmare are you using?

Comment: I am using version 2.5.3 and nightmare-iframe 1.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nightmare-iframe` is not compatible with Nightmare >2.x - it expects to be able to call into PhantomJS' `switchToFrame`, which does not exist in Electron.

From here, I think you have two options:

1. **Fall back to Nightmare 1.8.x.** It's no longer supported (to the best of my knowledge), but it runs with PhantomJS as the backing renderer.
2. **Use a different library.** [This PR](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/pull/496) was proposed as a fix for [the long-standing iframe issue](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/203) when running with Electron as a possible way to get Nightmare to perform similar sorts of actions as the ones you need.  I rewrote it as a [plugin](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-iframe-manager), which may be useful to you.  (That plugin is *very* dangerous.  Use with care.)

For completeness, I should also point out that native iframe support [has been proposed](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/593) for the next major revision of Nightmare.